# How do I install 64 bit version of mongodb on Ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am running into a very frustrating problem, where I follow the installation instructions `sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen` from 10gen on install mongodb on ubuntu 64 bit, but it **ALWAYS** installs the 32 version!

How do I force the installation of a 64 bit version on Ubuntu 10.4?

```
Fri Jun  7 03:12:51.436 [initandlisten] 
Fri Jun  7 03:12:51.436 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary. 
Fri Jun  7 03:12:51.436 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal). 
Fri Jun  7 03:12:51.436 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently off. 
Fri Jun  7 03:12:51.436 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit 
Fri Jun  7 03:12:51.437 [initandlisten]
```

### Update

When trying to force the architecture flag, the package cannot be found? Is there a problem with my available packages list?

```
> victorstan@li243-166:~$ sudo apt-get install -o
> apt::architecture=amd64 mongodb-10gen=2.4.4 Reading package lists...
> Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E:
> Couldn't find package mongodb-10gen
```

Note, when I first do my package updates I get a warning:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/downloads-distro.mongodb.org_repo_ubuntu-upstart_dists_dist_10gen_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

### Update

The NOTE shows independently your system is 32bit. Before try to fix you must check if your Ubuntu is 32 bit in that case just ignore the NOTE

Comment: your system is 64-bit?

Comment: My system is a Linode 3.9.2 x86_64

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: The problem ended up being that I was using a 32 bit linux DISTRIBUTION with 64 Bit KERNEL. Because I was using the 64 bit kernel I assumed I was also using a 64 bit distribution, which was not the case...

Answer (score 2):

You can force the installation to choose the amd64 version with the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install -o  apt::architecture=amd64  mongodb-10gen=2.4.4
```

(Follow the instructions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#configure-package-management-system-apt) to update apt)

Comment: Of course it should be noted that to force apt to seek an architecture it cannot detect is an inheritantly broken method

Comment: Thanks @jimoleary, but I updated my question with the issue I get when trying to force the architecture, basically the package cannot be found... I've been working with these instructions to set things up: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: odd ... I only get that error if `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list` is missing or I haven't run `sudo apt-get update`